# Using the JSSOR Slider with jquery - Force Caption Playout prior to Next Caption

Tags: jquery, slider

Is it possible to force Caption #1 to playout prior to Caption #2 starting, so that you could have text in the same location on the slide?  I have thoroughly reviewed the code and tried different caption options including t3 (playout immediately) but what I really need is for one  caption to play in, "HELLO WORLD" and then after a specific time playout and have "HELLO WORLD 2" playin where "HELLO WORLD" was.

I can get two captions to playin at the same location, but for obvious reasons this doesn't work because you cannot read the second caption with the first one under it.

Answer (score 0):

Given 2 captions locate at the same position, one covers the other then.

#1 caption can play out (by 't3') before #2 caption play in.

see http://www.jssor.com/testcase/caption.source.html